# How can I use the `time` command IN a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash

I often use `time` to time a command via console:

```
time PGPASSWORD=postgres psql -U postgres -h localhost -f init.sql
```

I now created a shell script which does the same:

```
#!/bin/sh
time PGPASSWORD=postgres psql -U postgres -h localhost -f init.sql
```

Now I get the following error:

> time: cannot run PGPASSWORD=postgres: No such file or directory
>    Command exited with non-zero status 127

How can I use `time` in a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bash` defines `time` as a pre-command modifier; `/bin/sh` is just running the external command `time`. You probably want `#!/bin/bash` as your shebang.